# Responsive image map on Bootstrap that works on mobile too

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, imagemap

i'm working on this website http://zag-test.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/website/intime2.html and as you can see i've an image map on the right side. To make it i've used https://www.image-maps.com/

I need help for the mobile version:

How can i make it work on mobile? If you check it on smartphone when you click on the single "map point" what happens is just a page refresh. How can i solve it?

This is the HTML code:

```
<div class="clock">
        <img class="img-responsive" id="Image-Maps-Com-image-maps-2015-10-01-031428" src="http://zag-test.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/website/base.png" border="0" width="434" height="420" orgWidth="434" orgHeight="420" usemap="#image-maps-2015-10-01-031428" alt="" />
<map name="image-maps-2015-10-01-031428" id="ImageMapsCom-image-maps-2015-10-01-031428">
<area shape="rect" coords="432,418,434,420" alt="Image Map" style="outline:none;" title="Image Map" href="http://www.image-maps.com/index.php?aff=mapped_users_60334" />
<area  alt="" title="" href="" shape="poly" coords="18,295,124,405,167,310,125,258" style="outline:none;"  target="_self" onclick="http://zag- test.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/website/1.png"  onmouseover="if(document.images) document.getElementById('Image-Maps-Com- image-maps-2015-10-01-031428').src= 'http://zag- test.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/website/1.png';"  onmouseout="if(document.images) document.getElementById('Image-Maps-Com- image-maps-2015-10-01-031428').src= 'http://zag- test.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/website/base.png';"  />
<area  alt="" title="" href="" shape="poly" coords="21,136,19,286,111,245,120,180" style="outline:none;" target="_self" onclick="http://zag-test.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/website/2.png" onmouseover="if(document.images) document.getElementById('Image-Maps-Com-image-maps-2015-10-01-031428').src= 'http://zag-test.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/website/2.png';" onmouseout="if(document.images) document.getElementById('Image-Maps-Com-image-maps-2015-10-01-031428').src= 'http://zag-test.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/website/base.png';"  />
<area  alt="" title="" href="" shape="poly" coords="23,124,135,20,179,124,128,170" style="outline:none;" target="_self" onclick="http://zag-test.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/website/3.png" onmouseover="if(document.images) document.getElementById('Image-Maps-Com-image-maps-2015-10-01-031428').src= 'http://zag-test.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/website/3.png';" onmouseout="if(document.images) document.getElementById('Image-Maps-Com-image-maps-2015-10-01-031428').src= 'http://zag-test.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/website/base.png';"  />
<area  alt="" title="" href="" shape="poly" coords="144,17,298,19,256,123,183,123" style="outline:none;" target="_self" onclick="http://zag-test.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/website/4.png" onmouseover="if(document.images) document.getElementById('Image-Maps-Com-image-maps-2015-10-01-031428').src= 'http://zag-test.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/website/4.png';" onmouseout="if(document.images) document.getElementById('Image-Maps-Com-image-maps-2015-10-01-031428').src= 'http://zag-test.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/website/base.png';"  />
<area  alt="" title="" href="" shape="poly" coords="306,23,413,136,310,178,261,128" style="outline:none;" target="_self" onclick="http://zag-test.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/website/5.png" onmouseover="if(document.images) document.getElementById('Image-Maps-Com-image-maps-2015-10-01-031428').src= 'http://zag-test.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/website/5.png';" onmouseout="if(document.images) document.getElementById('Image-Maps-Com-image-maps-2015-10-01-031428').src= 'http://zag-test.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/website/base.png';"  />
<area  alt="" title="" href="" shape="poly" coords="414,299,416,142,310,182,312,253" style="outline:none;" target="_self" onclick="http://zag-test.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/website6.png" onmouseover="if(document.images) document.getElementById('Image-Maps-Com-image-maps-2015-10-01-031428').src= 'http://zag-test.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/website/6.png';" onmouseout="if(document.images) document.getElementById('Image-Maps-Com-image-maps-2015-10-01-031428').src= 'http://zag-test.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/website/base.png';"  />
<area  alt="" title="" href="" shape="poly" coords="296,413,413,305,309,258,255,307" style="outline:none;" target="_self" onclick="http://zag-test.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/website/7.png" onmouseover="if(document.images) document.getElementById('Image-Maps-Com-image-maps-2015-10-01-031428').src= 'http://zag-test.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/website/7.png';" onmouseout="if(document.images) document.getElementById('Image-Maps-Com-image-maps-2015-10-01-031428').src= 'http://zag-test.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/website/base.png';"  />
```

Comment: What would you expect to happens with this map on mobile?

Comment: @s.kwiotek the same things that happens on desktop. When you touch a single "slice" you can see the hover effect.

Comment: Ok. So you have to handle Touch-Event like your onmouseover/onmouseout. Do you have a mobile JS Library?

Comment: @s.kwiotek nope. Not actually...

Comment: So please have a look at http://www.w3.org/TR/touch-events/

Comment: @s.kwiotek i Will check. If i have problem i'll write here